# Implementation of a watchdog in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, shell, process, watchdog

I need to contain execution of an external process (a command line call) into a fixed time window.

After few readings I coded up this implementation:

```
#/bin/perl -w

use IPC::System::Simple qw( capture );

use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use warnings;

my $timeout = 4;
share($timeout);

my $stdout;
share($stdout);

my $can_proceed = 1;
share($can_proceed);

sub watchdogFork {
    my $time1 = time;

    my $ml = async {
        my $sleepTime = 2;
        my $thr = threads->self();
        $stdout = capture("sleep $sleepTime; echo \"Good morning\n\";");
        print "From ml: " . $stdout;
        $thr->detach();
    };

    my $time2;
    do {
        $time2 = time - $time1;
    } while ( $time2 < $timeout );
    print "\n";

    if ( $ml->is_running() ) {
        print "From watchdog: timeout!\n";
        $can_proceed = 0;
        $ml->detach();
    }
}
my $wd = threads->create('watchdogFork');
$wd->join();

print "From main: " . $stdout if ($can_proceed);
```

When `$timeout > $sleepTime` it returns:

```
From ml: Good morning
From main: Good morning
```

Other hand, when `$timeout < $sleepTime`:

```
From watchdog: timeout!
```

The behaviour obtained is correct but I think that this approach is slightly raw.

I was wondering if there are libraries that could help to refine the source code improving readability and performances. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

[IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) allows you to run child processes and interact with their `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. You can also set [timeouts](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm#Timeouts_and_Timers), which throw an exception when exceeded:

```
use IPC::Run qw(harness run timeout);

my @cmd = qw(sleep 10); 
my $harness = harness \@cmd, \undef, \my $out, \my $err, timeout(3);

eval {
    run $harness or die "sleep: $?";
};
if ($@) {
    my $exception = $@; # Preserve $@ in case another exception occurs
    $harness->kill_kill;

    print $exception; # and continue with the rest of the program
}
```

Note that there are some [limitations when running on Windows](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm#Win32_LIMITATIONS).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timeout_system` from [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm):

```
use Proc::Background qw(timeout_system);

my $wait_status = timeout_system($seconds, $command, $arg1, $arg2);
my $exit_code = $wait_status >> 8;
```

The process will be killed after `$seconds` seconds.

Comment: Ok. Within this method, i guess, the only way to redirect *stdout and stderr streams* to a perl array, is to pass through shell output redirection operators and fill a text file. Then read lines from it. Or am i wrong? I mean, or is there a better way?

Comment: @FilippoLauria There are other ways. For example, [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.23/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm): `use Capture::Tiny qw(capture); use Proc::Background qw(timeout_system); my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture { timeout_system($seconds, $command); };` Not sure this is the *best* way, but it's an option.